# div equal height animation on document ready

Tags: html, jquery

I have a script called equal-heights.js which works together with underscore.js. It equalize the divs to the size of the highest div with an animation (optional). The problem is that when I charge the page nothing happens, it starts to equalize the divs only when I resize the browser.

The initialising code on the HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.profile-panel').equalHeights({
        responsive:true,
        animate:true,
        animateSpeed:500
    });

});
```

You can see the equal-heights.js here: http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com/templates/js/blogger-equal-heights-responsive.js

What should I do so that, when the page loads, the animation starts to equalize the divs automatically?

Comment: would be great if you could setup a working example / demo, it's hard to tell this way what you may be doing wrong... recommend http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: maybe it helps for you, this is the demo page of the js : http://optdesign.co.uk/equal-heights-responsive/

Comment: that's fine, but what i mean something more specific to your situation, ie, try to model your case... the above example will only show me how it's supposed to work, but won't allow me to tell you why it's not working for you...

Comment: ...let me try to help you (but as i don't see the rest of your code, these are really just guesses): have you added your code in the `head` (that's where it is in your example)? do you have the same or similar html structure as that example? are you calling the right selector (`.profile-panel`) - the example seems like calling one of the selectors that each have the same name...

Comment: look at it here : http://www.igorlaszlo.com/test/test/profile.html  i worked on it locally, i had to put it on line, now you can see it..

Comment: which columns do you want to have equal heights? you don't even have side by side columns here...

Comment: ah, wait 2 minutes please, i must update the test !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64460/discussion-between-webeno-and-igor-laszlo).

Comment: another thing you may want to try: use `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()`...

Comment: for the record, i created a fiddle based on the previous example you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/o9rjvq8j/1/

Comment: with window load, it does the same thing... in the jsfiddle you put animation option in the code but it does not do animation when i go to see the page... mine does, but only after resizing the browser screen... many misterious things :)))

Comment: just provided an answer, hope it will work for you, it did for me after i recreated your example on my side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created my own test and realized the issue is with the way the plugin has been written, namely that it only accepts one value for the class name, otherwise it will break.

This is because of the following line in the script:

```
className = '.'+$(this).prop('class');
```

What this does is that it takes the `class` property of your element and adds a dot (`.`) in front; a nice but not very scalable way of getting the current selector, because if you have multiple class names, it will only put a dot in front of the first one, so if you have...

```
<div class="profile-panel profile-panel-1st-row profile-panel1">
```

...it will transform it into...

```
$('.profile-panel profile-panel-1st-row profile-panel1')
```

...so understandably this will not work properly, as the dots are missing from the rest of the classes.

To go around this, until version 1.7, jQuery had a [.selector](http://api.jquery.com/selector/) property, that however has now been deprecated. Instead they're now suggesting to add the selector as an argument of your plugin's function as follows (and I tailored it to your situation):

First define an option called `selector` when calling the function:

```
$('.profile-panel-1st-row').equalHeights({
        selector:'.profile-panel-1st-row',
        // ...
    });
```

Then setup the `className` variable inside the plugin as follows:

```
var className = options.selector;
```

Another thing you can do is the place the class you're using to activate the plugin as the first one for each element you want to use it on, so instead of...

```
<div class="profile-panel profile-panel-1st-row profile-panel1">
```

...do this...

```
<div class="profile-panel-1st-row profile-panel profile-panel1">
```

...then you can setup the `className` variable inside the plugin as follows:

```
var className = '.'+ $(this).prop('class').split(" ").slice(0,1);
```

This basically splits the class names into parts divided by space and takes the first one.

To have the best of both solutions, simply set `className` to the following:

```
var className = options.selector || '.'+ $(this).prop('class').split(" ").slice(0,1);
```

As to the animation, it only works on resize; that is intended, that's how the plugin has been built, you can play around with the original example of the plugin creator that I added to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o9rjvq8j/1/

**EDIT #2**: If you're happy to change the plugin even more, just remove `$(window).resize(function()` in the `if(settings.responsive === true)` check and you'll have it working. ;)

```
if(settings.responsive === true) {
    //reset height to auto
    $(className).css("height","auto");
    //re initialise
    reInit();
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you ! The three rows work now but i still have my initial question, how can we make the animation working on the page load and not after resizing the browser ? :)

Comment: I realized another problem too : my last panel resizes at the first browser resize but when i continue resizing the browser screen, it remains the same height... i think i will get back to the display:table-cell solution, this plugin is not bad but not ready yet to use it...

Comment: checkout my edit at the bottom of my answer; I think it's the answer to your initial question ;)

Comment: Yes, that is it ! The code resize-window must be deleted in the js file and now the animation executes automatically at page load ! You deserve for your point, you answered for what i wanted to know, however, the plugin does not work perfectly yet, when we resize the window for very small (300px wide), the panels doe not fllow the highest panel size...